# REGEXP_SUBSTR function equivalent in Oracle 9i?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split, oracle9i

Is there an equivalent function for `regexp_substr` in Oracle 9i.

I know `regexp_substr` came in Oracle 10g onwards.

Trying to figure out a way if I can use the same function logic in Oracle 9i.

I have data like

```
0/6/03/19
0/6/3/19
0/1/3/09
```

I want to pick out the values separately by delimiting the string with / .

I tried using `substr` and `instr` but it won't be generic as the length of the string between slashes can change.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated the question with data

Comment: This isn't the sort of problem in general for which databases are well suited.  It's good that you're trying to normalize your data, but you might have a much easier time doing this outside of Oracle (e.g. in Java).  Even `REGEXP_SUBSTR` might not help here if the number of paths is unknown and could be variable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Java's not an option as it should happen through a pl/sql script...

Comment: Then you're going to need a UDF or maybe a proc.  I don't know enough Oracle to give an answer.

Comment: Sure you can do it with PL/SQL. What output do you want exactly? Some examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only use `instr` and `substr` combination as :

```
with t as
(
  select '0/6/03/19' as str from dual union all
  select '0/6/3/19' from dual
)
select substr(str,1,instr(str,'/',1,1)-1) str1,
       substr(str,instr(str,'/',1,1)+1,instr(str,'/',1,2)-instr(str,'/',1,1)-1) str2,
       substr(str,instr(str,'/',1,2)+1,instr(str,'/',1,3)-instr(str,'/',1,2)-1) str3,
       substr(str,instr(str,'/',1,3)+1,length(str)-instr(str,'/',1,3)) str4
  from t;

STR1    STR2    STR3    STR4
----    ----    ----    ----
 0       6       03      19
 0       6        3      19
```

*P.S. If your DB's version is 9.2 then `with .. as` structure may be used as above.*

you can also get the results *row-wise*(in *unpivot manner*) as :

```
with t as
(
 select '/'||str||'/' as str, ID
   from
   (
    select 1 as ID, '0/6/03/19' as str from dual union all
    select 2,'0/6/3/19' from dual
   )
)
select
      distinct ID, level as piece_nr,
      substr(str,instr(str,'/',1,level)+1,instr(str,'/',1,level+1)-instr(str,'/',1,level)-1)
      as piece_value
  from ( select * from t )
connect by level <= length(str)-length(replace(str,'/',''))-1
  order by ID, level;

ID  PIECE_NR    PIECE_VALUE
--  --------  -----------
1        1           0
1        2           6
1        3           03
1        4           19
2        1           0
2        2           6
2        3           3
2        4           19
```

Comment: HI , the oracle version is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.4.0

but when I run the above query , I get the error 


ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing

Comment: @826dna ok, edited, took `str` inside brackets. Version 9.2 supports `with <table> as` but `with <table>(<col1>,...) as`.